# PL/SQL - como ver a quantidade de linhas manipuladas através de uma trigger?

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Eu já tentei com o `sql%rowcount` mas quando é uma trigger ele simplesmente não funciona.. como eu posso retornar o numero de linhas manipuladas em uma instrução DML a partir de uma trigger?

Comment: Só faria sentido para STATEMENT e AFTER , em que condições você precisa disto?

Comment: Estou tentando criar uma trigger que impede um update ou delete sem where, para isso eu preciso saber o numero de linhas que estão sendo manipuladas e se esse numero de linhas for igual ao numero de linhas no banco (select count(*) from tabela) eu subo uma mensagem de erro.

Comment: Para isto BD tem backup , chave estrangeiea etc. O acesso de sql direto a bd de producào deve ser controlado e aplicações só devdm "subir" após teste , banco de teste serve oara isto , no máximo ter um script de carga se der slgum erro.O foco seria outro.